# I'm getting a CORS policy issue when trying to redirect to Azure AD for authentication

Tags: angular, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-msal, oidc-client

I'm getting this error:

`Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenantId}/oauth2/v2.0/authorize/.well-known/openid-configuration' from origin 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.`

when trying to redirect to azure for login.

Here's the service:

```
export class AuthService {
private _userManager: UserManager;

constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
    const config = {
        authority: Constants.stsAuthority,
        client_id: Constants.clientId,
        redirect_uri: `${Constants.clientRoot}assets/oidc-login-redirect.html`,
        scope: 'openid profile',
        response_type: 'id_token token',
        post_logout_redirect_uri: `${Constants.clientRoot}?postLogout=true`,
        userStore: new WebStorageStateStore({ store: window.localStorage })
      };
    this._userManager = new UserManager(config)
 }

 login(): Promise<any>{
     return this._userManager.signinRedirect();
 }
```

}

I'm sure I registered correctly my `localhost` url. Yet, I'm getting that error. So far, I didn't see any documentation dealing with that.

Thanks for helping

[image]

Comment: http://restlet.com/blog/2016/09/27/how-to-fix-cors-problems/ , your azure server should allow requests from different domain

Comment: I'm not trying to access my azure application. I'm trying to authenticate using `Active Directory.`

Comment: Well my point was CORS is the server's problem it doesn't have to do anything with angular/javascript

Answer (score 3, accepted):

https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenantId}/oauth2/v2.0/authorize/.well-known/openid-configuration is not a valid URL.

Probably your authority is configured wrong. 
It should be just `https://login.microsoftonline.com/tenant-id`.

Comment: the `url` was the culprit. Yet, that's what was shown the tutorial I watched on YouTube. Now I'm getting a different error `AADSTS90002: Tenant not found. This may happen if there are no active subscriptions for the tenant. Check with your subscription administrator.`. However, at least I'm being redirected to Azure. Thank you so much.

Comment: Did you replace tenant-id with your actual tenant id?

Comment: Yes. I went to `Properties` page and copied the value of `Directory ID`. What's strange is that it's complaining about a tenant ID that I didn't send, i.e. My `Directory ID` is different from the `Tenant ID` AD complaints that it can't find.

Comment: I see now why I was getting that error. It's because I was using my free account to test the concept. Now I'm using my company subscription, so I solved the problem. Thank you again.